# What are the disadvantages of using Snowflake's own native stage compared to having S3 as a stage area

Tags: amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have 2 options for my use case.

1. Using Informatica PowerCenter to directly connect to Snowflake and load data using Snowflake's native staging area
2. Loading data into S3 first using Informatica PC and using S3 as the staging area fo load data into Snowflake

In both cases my source is On-premise DB and files. Please advise on the best approach.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't anything different about these options from a cost or performance basis.  Option #1 still uses S3, but Snowflake-managed, while Option #2 uses your own S3.  My 2 cents on these options, though, are the following:

Option #1 is easier to setup and manage from within your data pipeline and Informatica flow.  There are just less objects to manage.  However, you also lose control over managing the files on S3, since that is managed by Snowflake.

Option #2 is more complicated to setup, but provides you with more flexibility with how you manage the files on S3 from a retention, organization, etc. perspective.

If you wish to have control over the files that are produced on S3, go with Option #2.  Otherwise, if you don't really care that much about intermediate files like the ones that Informatica is likely producing in this case, then I'd go with Option #1.

Hope that helps...and again, just my opinion.